# Minimum hardware required for headphones monitoring?

Tags: microphone, headphones, hardware, monitoring

One reason I use DT-770's is for their sound isolation. However this sometimes works against me when I need to be hearing my own voice in addition to whatever is normally coming in through the headphones.

[image]

I would like to feed back my microphone input into my headphones with as little latency as possible.

### Existing setup:

`Audio Source (Laptop or other)` -> `Headphones`

`Microphone`

### Desired outcome

`Audio Source (Laptop or other)` + `Microphone` -> `Headphones`

What is the bare minimum *hardware* I would need to introduce *monitoring* into a setup consisting of headphones and an audio source?

Would a single mixer do the job? Or would I need something to amplify the microphone before it goes into the mixer?

Comment: I appreciate the attention already on this question! To respond to the close vote linking to [this meta post](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/should-home-theater-non-studio-or-production-related-equipment-questions-be-on), I'd like to make the case that this question is still on-topic; namely that I'm not asking about home theater or consumer/prosumer, I'd perfectly fine doing the same thing a studio would given the need for monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard hack is to move one of the cans off your ear. 
Applications like Rogue Amoeba Loopback can route your mic input to the headphones. Loopback's latency is [20 ms](https://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2016/01/11/now-arriving-loopback/), I don't know if this is low enough.

Check the [settings for your internal mic](https://support.soundtrap.com/hc/en-us/articles/212356589-How-can-I-reduce-monitoring-latency-on-Mac-OS-X-): disable "Use ambient noise reduction" to reduce latency.

IDK if [Audio Hijack](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/audio-hijack-3-hidden-low-latency-mode) can do what you want?

If it's still too much latency, you could switch to an audio interface that has [direct monitoring.](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/search.php?s=audio%20interface%20direct%20monitoring) Direct monitoring means that the audio from the mic is routed to the headphones without going through the computer first.
Connect a microphone and your headphones to the interface.

That link didn't catch all interfaces with direct monitoring. [This one](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/UM2usb--behringer-u-phoria-um2-usb-audio-interface) for instance. So it's worth checking the specs on more audio interfaces.

Comment: Oooh, I'll try Loopback!

Comment: Hmm yeah, the latency is definitely more than I was expecting.  However low Loopback's real latency may be, it's coming off as a real _echo_ effect and triggers [DAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_Auditory_Feedback) for me.

Comment: Wow yeah Audio Hijack definitely gets the latency down into acceptable territory. I'll have to see how it works after using it for a bit and possibly purchase an audio interface like you linked to if I want to improve latency even further. Thanks so much @Hobbes!

Comment: Loopback would be twice the price of a hardware interface, Audio Hijack about the same as an entry-level system. Neither could cope if the mic was USB. The question is honestly too vague to be answered without follow-up questions.. not least "are you on a Mac?" & "What mic are we talking about?"

Comment: @Tetsujin that info was present in the initial version of the question (Mac laptop, internal mic)

Comment: Yeah, I am currently using a MacBook Pro with the internal mic, but folks started voting to close because the question was too oriented towards non-pro equipment. So if removing that info makes the question too general... then maybe this kind of question just doesn't belong here? Also Loopback is $99 and all of the hardware from Hobbe's link costs more than that. What would cost less?

Comment: Cheaper ones are available. As for the question belonging here: some users here are trigger-happy on the close votes. This question applies to a range of situations from home audio to audio production, so I'd consider it to be on-topic.

Comment: Steinberg make interfaces that allow you to mix the input signal with the output signal for monitoring purposes. That would suit you well.